# how to give a domain name to google cloud launcher built Drupal instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google cloud launcher to set up a Drupal instance. It went quite well. But the problem is that I can only access the drupal site by the ip address, which is http://146.148.100.235. Hope someone can advise me on how to set up a domain name under Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in Google Cloud DNS (https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart) and Google Domains (https://domains.google/#/).

You can purchase a domain name from Google Domains and then use the dns servers from Cloud DNS